# Showing more months in Monthlyarchive.aspx in a Blog-subsite

Tags: blog

So if I created a blog-subsite in August 2011, the Monthlyarchive.aspx is going to show me months from August 2011 onwards.

Let's say that I want to create a blog-post now in January 2012 **but** I want it to say that it was created in June 2011 and I want this to be shown correctly in the Monthlyarchive.aspx. So instead of showing all the months from August 2011 onwards, it would show all the months starting from June 2011. And then when you click on June 2011, it would show the post I created now in January 2012.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this doesn't look to be possible out-of-the-box.

There is a [Codeplex](http://sp2010bstawp.codeplex.com/.) project that addresses this limitation.  They acknowledge SP2010 *does not support provisioning of pre-dated posts* and provide an alternative web part that works with pre-dated posts.

Comment: This add-in is nice but does not work perfectly.  It failed for me with my blog on a subsite with a 404 file not found error when I tried to browse to a month.  The code that does `SPContext.Current.Site + SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl` was resulting in the site collection showing up twice in the url.  I changed it to `SPContext.Current.Web.Url` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use a DataView web part or XSLT View web part to rebuild the behavior. see here for an example http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/how-to-display-sharepoint-blog-post-archives/